# Prevent an R file from running in a package

Tags: r-package

I have a package I want to use for internal use. One of the files queries our database, cleans the data, then saves the data with `devtools::use_data(sql_data)`.

The problem is, this file is run every-time I load the library. I would like to hide this file so it does not run when I load. Instead, I am thinking of writing a function to source the file when I would like the data updated.

How can I prevent this file from running everytime I run `library(my_package)`?

Comment: Nothing should be run when you load a library (excepted what is in `.onLoad`, e.g. [here](https://github.com/privefl/bigstatsr/blob/master/R/zzz.R#L3-L11)).

Comment: @F.Privé Also, how do I prevent the R files from running on install. `devtools::install("..path/to/my_package")`

Comment: You mean the ones in `R/`? There should be nothing to run inside of them (only functions).